# syntax error :(hbase):37: lbunknown regex options - lb

Tags: hbase, hdfs

I have fired below query to loading from hdfs file to Hbase.
HDFS input path is 'sales_data/ex1data.csv'

Query :

```
hadoop jar /usr/lib/hbase/hbase.jar importtsv -libjars /usr/lib/hbase/lib/guava-11.0.2.jar '-Dimporttsv.separator=,' -Dimporttsv.columns=HBASE_ROW_KEY,location:s_borough,location:s_neighbor,location:s_b_class,location:s_c_p,location:s_block,location:s_lot,location:s_easement,location:w_c_p_2,location:s_address,location:s_app_num,location:s_zip,units:s_res_units,units:s_com_units,units:s_tot_units,size:s_sq_ft,size:s_g_sq_ft,age:s_yr_built,pricing:s_tax_c,pricing:s_b_class2,pricing:s_price,pricing:s_sales_dt sales_data  sales_data/ex1data.csv
```

Error:

> syntax error :(hbase):37: lbunknown regex options - lb

Please help with this error.

Thank you!!

Comment: Did you found an answer ?